# Web intent url getting modifying automatically

Tags: android, android-intent

I trying to a webpage link so for this I am using following code

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://example.com/privacy"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

when I click on link, it open in web browser and go to proper page, when i press again on app link and open it again web browser its URL get modifying automatically, on second click i get URL like this
`"https://http//example.com/privacy"` I don't why this is happening

Comment: try to show your code here

Comment: my code is already added in question, I am using browserIntent to open web url

Comment: see answer thats how you need to parse url in browser intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find bug in my code

my string file had anchor tag attached thats why new url getting added to intent

this ling had bug

```
<string name="txt_terms_and_conditions"><a href='https://http://example.com/privacy'>By clicking the Send OTP option,\n you agree to our Terms and Conditions</a></string>
```

so I removed anchor tag so it working normally

Comment: you passed uri from file ?

Comment: yes I am also sending uri from code and some other developer in team added anchor tag in xml file so it causing problem.

Comment: you should have provided your file also in your problem

Comment: I dont know about such thing before posting problem, I first time encountered such Anchor tag for intent redirection :)